# Angular app how to load all assets from /assets local project directory on app init

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to load all /assets local folder before my app init. Now only images that I currently need when the app starts are being loaded. How to avoid that and load all of them?

Comment: you can create one single bundle using webpack, it has various options to manage what will be in your initial bundle.

Comment: @Yaroslav thank you! do u have any example, how to do that properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file.txt in your assets folder (*) with all the files, read using httpClient and read the images. Some like

```
export function initializeAppFactory(httpClient: HttpClient):
   () => Observable<any> {
     return ()=>
         httpClient.get('./assets/files.txt',{responseType: 'text'})
           .pipe(switchMap((res:any)=>{
              const files=res.split("\r\n")
              return forkJoin(files
                  .map((f:string)=>httpClient.get('./assets/'+f,
                      { observe: 'response' })))
    }),tap(()=>{
      console.log("ready")
    }))
}
```

(*)It's difficult read the files of a directory

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-acpbvt?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fassets%2Ffiles.txt&title=Angular%20Starter) (see that in console goes "ready" before show the application and using F12 you see that the files are readed)

**Update**

Aclaration about the code: The idea is that, e.g. res get the value `"file1.jpg\n\rfile2.jpg\n\r", files becomes` ["file1.jpg","file2.jpg"]`, the forkjoin makes all the calls.

So, possible we need need filter to be sure the files has value:

```
const files=res.split("\r\n").filter((x:any)=>x)
```

This avoid if in files.txt there're a new line. BTW We can check the Check the response when you read the file

```
console.log(res,files)
```

Well, we can improve the function to take account we add a file that not exist.

```
export function initializeAppFactory(
  httpClient: HttpClient
): () => Observable<any> {
  return () =>
    httpClient.get('./assets/files.txt', { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
      switchMap((res: any) => {
        const files = res.split('\r\n').filter((x: any) => x);
        return forkJoin(
          files.map((f: string) =>
            httpClient.get('./assets/' + f, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
              catchError((error: any) => {
                console.log('file not found: ' + f, error);
                return EMPTY;
              })
            )
          )
        );
      }),
      tap(() => {
        console.log('ready');
      })
    );
}
```

just update in the stackblitz

Comment: Thank you so much, it's almost working, I have rewritten the syntax to the newer Angular version but this line is causing an error             return forkJoin(files.map((f: string) => this.httpClient.get('assets/' + f)));
it's requesting to /assets directory itself and the response is being canceled and app being broken. Do u know how to fixed that?

Comment: @W12, I update the answer. I feel that your file.txt has a new line or similar or a file not exist. We need take account that, if one file is not exist we app crash

Comment: I have replaced forkJoin with combineLatest and switchMap with mergeMap and it's getting assets perfectly. Do I have to replace images path to avoid getting them twice in 'images' network tab and replace with those from our http req?