# Angular: Bad-user experience as i18n is not loaded before component has been loaded

Tags: angular, internationalization

We have built a website in Angular and we had some discussions in our team on, whats the best way, to load i18n first - before creating components?

Right, now a user might be able, to see the i18n variables being visible on our website, because the i18n Translate loader havent been loaded.

How do we make sure, the i18n is loaded, before displaying the content to the user?

Our website: https://stellarsecurity.com/

Where you might see, what I mean.

We load the TranslateLoader on our app.module.ts

and on app.component.ts, we set the language:

```
let language = navigator.language;

    language = language.substring(0, 2);

    this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'de', 'da']);
    this.translate.use(language);
```

Comment: If you're asking about how "preload" a file, you can use APP_INITIALIZER to "preload" like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77411355/best-way-to-inline-svgs-in-angular-universal/77411660#77411660). You can also use a "skeleton preloader" (you can check this [Netanel basal's article](https://netbasal.com/implementing-a-loading-skeleton-in-angular-7490ffdecc1b). NOTE: Check your server, the .json is not loaded because it's redirect to 404.html page